# Explain performance schema count_star

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-8.0

Can you please explain MySQL 8

```
performance_schema events_statements_summary_by_digest count_start
```

?

```
+------------+----------------+
| COUNT_STAR | SUM_TIMER_WAIT |
+------------+----------------+
|      21562 |  1422617337000 |
|       5134 |   231538954000 |
|       5134 | 42625981791000 |
|        184 |     6224664000 |
|         65 |    67034144000 |
|         48 |    80661283000 |
|         39 |    25631638000 |
|         32 |     1131746000 |
|         32 |     1206939000 |
|         32 |     5997462000 |
|         20 |     2349761000 |
|          8 |      284036000 |
|          8 |     2976134000 |
|          7 |     1254130000 |
|          6 |     1792915000 |
|          6 |      784386000 |
|          6 |      821875000 |
|          6 |     1102248000 |
|          6 |     1079227000 |
|          5 |    11042289000 |
|          5 |     4207319000 |
|          5 |     4012671000 |
|          5 |     6844824000 |
+------------+----------------+
```

I found this in documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/wait-summary-tables.html but it's hard to understand for me.

```
COUNT_STAR

The number of summarized events. This value includes all events, whether timed or nontimed.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is unclear in the definition?

Comment: @Shadow now all good, under 21562 goes all laravel queries, so that why i cant find my real queries. 

So count star is number of queries times run?

Comment: Please provide something like this so we can discuss further (and provide text, not an image):  `select * from performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest count_start LIMIT 2\G
`

Comment: So is this the time events that the query is waiting for before it executes, or are these the times events the query is causing, as in it's making other things wait.